# Disable picturebox_click event on vb.net

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I'm using a click event on a picture box, that can only be enabled after some actions.

```
Private Sub PictureBox_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox.Click
```

But i want to disable that click without using `picturebox.enabled=false` cause it changes the original colour to grey.

How can i do that ? Thank you!

Comment: remove the click event? this can be found in the event properties of the picturebox.

Comment: @Werdna ye sure. and how do i use it when i want to actually use the picture click?

Comment: you could set up a boolean I guess, you need to show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities.

1. You use a boolean value indicating that you don't want to run the logic in the event handler.

   Here is an example:

   ```
   Private _usePictureBoxEvent as Boolean = True

   Private Sub PictureBox_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox.Click
       If _usePictureBoxEvent Then
           'Do your event stuff here
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

   To deactivate the event handling:

   ```
   _usePictureBoxEvent = False 'the event will still be activated but we'll do nothing
   ```
2. Dynamically subscribe to the event: `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler`

   Here's an example:

   ```
   Public Sub New()
       'VS calls this, don't touch
       InitializeComponents()

       'We add a listener to this event
       AddHandler Me.PictureBox.Click, AddressOf PictureBox_Click_1

       'Other stuff
   End Sub

   Private Sub PictureBox_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 'No more Handles clause
       'Do your event stuff

   End Sub
   ```

   And to stop the event from triggering:

   ```
   'Anywhere in your code
   RemoveHandler Me.PictureBox.Click, AddressOf PictureBox_Click_1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a static event handler ( Handles [...] ) is a bit harder to remove it.

The easiest and cleanest solution would be to have a boolean and check its value on the event (and changing it where you need to allow/disallow it).

Or change it to a non-static handler: AddHandler/RemoveHandler.

Other solutions would imply inheriting the PictureBox and overriding the OnClick method.